# windows copy files on the basis of modified date

Tags: windows, copy

I have thousands of .csv file from Jan-2013 to Dec-2013.
I want to copy files from Jan-2013 to Oct-2013 in a backup directory. please suggest copy command with date arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no command that would completely solve your task.

You might want to look at xcopy. It is available in some windows distros. Just type xcopy /? in terminal and see. If it is not available you can download it.

xcopy has a switch /D that will allow you to copy only files with "modified" date later then specified.

Here is the minimal example

```
xcopy c:/temp/* c:/backup /D:1-1-13
```

This will copy all files modified after 1st of January 2013 from c:/temp/ to c:/backup

As far as I know copying files between to dates can only be done by writing a script or a program. There is no standard tool for it.

I hope this helps, if you need more help - don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

`Robocopy.exe` has `/MINAGE` and `/MAXAGE` arguments.

You didn't specify your Windows version, but I think Robocopy has been provided with Windows since Vista. For older Windows versions, you can download [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).